# Beautiful Soup parsing an XML file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a simple Python using Beautiful Soup to parse the data I need out of an xml file. It's working how I need it to, but I have one ask of you guys as I have tried to Google this but can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Sample of XML string:

```
<ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="Attachment Type" PADBAttribute="N" RecordNumber="1" LanguageCode="EN">Clamp-On</ProductAttribute>
```

I am needing the **AttributeID** within the ProductAttribute. When I write, the below I am able to grab the value "Clamp-On" but I need AttributeID to tell me what Clamp-On is referencing.

```
attributes[part.find('PartNumber').get_text()] = [x.get_text() for x in part.find_all('ProductAttribute')]

for key, value in attributes.items():
     for v in value:
     print(v)
```

Any guidance is appreciated before negative feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the x.get_text() is bypassing the tag-level attributes

Comment: You can select attributes by key - [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

Comment: Thanks guys, I had just stumbled across that as you guys commented.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using only `lxml` library:

```
from lxml import etree

xml_string = """<ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="Attachment Type" PADBAttribute="N" RecordNumber="1" LanguageCode="EN">Clamp-On</ProductAttribute>"""

xml = etree.XML(xml_string)
print(xml.get("AttributeID"))
```

**Output**:

```
Attachment Type
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how u can get a tag attribute from an xml using BeautifulSoup and lxml,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_string = '<ProductAttribute MaintenanceType="C" AttributeID="Attachment Type" PADBAttribute="N" RecordNumber="1" LanguageCode="EN">Clamp-On</ProductAttribute>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'xml')
tag = soup.ProductAttribute
print(tag['AttributeID'])
```

this code print the value of the attribute `AttributeID`